# grep search all whitespaces zero or more times

Tags: bash, shell, grep

When I try to find the source of warnings or error in my code, the output from the compiler is often pre-processed, such that white-space is not anymore the same as in the original code.

What is a nice way to transform the `grep` pattern with white-space like this:

```
grep 'data.frame(foo = x)' mycode
```

to

```
grep 'data.frame(foo *= *x)' mycode
```

?

---

One possibility, which I find a bit ugly:

```
PATTERN=`sed 's/ / */g' <(echo "test pattern") ` && grep $PATTERN mycode
```

Comment: If ugliness is the problem, why not just hide it in a script so that you don't have to look at?  Or, is there a different problem that you want to solve?

Comment: The only reason I don't like about the script solution is that I have to find out which of the arguments is the pattern. I think there is no easy way around?

Comment: The shell script would figure out which argument is the pattern and which is the file the same as `grep` does.  I added an example below based on your `sed` code.

Comment: The issue I have is when I use options, or `-e` for the pattern, which I would want to detect.

Comment: OK.  The ability to handle options has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
grep 'data.frame(foo = x)' mycode
```

Use:

```
mygrep  'data.frame(foo = x)' mycode
```

where `mygrep` is a file, with the executable bit set, containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a options
for arg in "$@"
do
    case "$arg" in
        -*) options+=("$arg") ; shift ;;
        *) break ;;
    esac
done
grep "${options[@]}" "$(sed 's/ / */g' <(echo "$1"))" "$2"
```

All the ugliness is hidden in the file.  The arguments are the same.  (Limitation: I haven't added the ability to handle options that take arguments for the special case where the option and its argument are separated by whitespace.)

Comment: That's nice. I replaced the `"$2"` with `${*:2}` when more files are supplied.

Comment: Further, I escape some of the special regexp characters (for now `[` and `]`) which are also appear in the code: `PATTERN="$(sed 's/ / */g;s/\[/\\[/g;s/\]/\\]/g' <(echo "$1"))".
`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
PATTERN=$(sed -r 's/\s+/\\s+/g' <<<"$PATTERN")
```

and then use `egrep` to allow using the extended regexp feature `\s` for whitespace.

Or in one step:

```
egrep "$(sed -r 's/\s+/\\s+/g' <<<"$PATTERN")" mycode
```